# Android SMS content provider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I have a client who want an app that would run "perfectly".

He asks me if there is any way of pulling off the entire list of SMSs for a certain contact in order to send it over to a webserver.

I know that the SMS content provider is not part of the official SDK but I don't understand what does this exactly mean.

Can anyone explain me the issues with the SMS CP and what are the risks of using it in my app?
Will the app still be able to run without issues, as my detail-oriented client wishes?

P.S. Do not close this question. I do not ask for personal opinions, I ask for technical explanations.

Thanks.

Comment: Just a warning. It's hard to make something run "perfectly" when using stuff not in the public API since there are no guarantee that it works (and will work) the same across all versions of android.

Answer (score 1):

It won't run perfectly, the SMS not being part of the public API's means its not guaranteed to be standard across the board, for example you may get your app working on standard Android on a Nexus device but HTC/Samsung and all other brands will have slightly different content providers depending on their needs and designs meaning your app will break on these content providers.